# Best practices for when to use the Try pattern in C#

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

After reading a bit on the topic, I am still unsure of *when* to provide TryGet*(someParameter, out someValue) methods.
I understand how it can be useful when there exists a variant of the method that can throw exceptions in the case of failure, but I can't really form a general rule that I can use to help me decide when to provide either type of method.

Some questions that come to mind about this:

- Why not just have the non-try method not throw exceptions?
- When would throwing an exception be better than just returning null?
- If the decision comes down to having one type of method that just returns a nullable type (or some Result type), should this always be reflected in the method's name in the sense that it has to be prefixed with "Try"?
- Is providing both types of methods always better in every case?

I am specifically working with manipulating a collection, and what I have is a bunch of methods like:
`void GetAt(position)`
`bool TryGetAt(position, out item)`

I'm not sure whether this is needed or not, but it feels like what I'm doing is wrong in some way.

Comment: Note that e.g. the `TryParse` methods were added specifically for performance reasons -- while throwing an exception is *relatively* quick, if you've got a tight loop which is trying and failing to parse numbers, that gets significant. In terms of which to write -- it depends on what the caller wants the method to do. If the caller expects the method to fail, it's easier to call a `TryXXX` method. If the caller expects the method to succeed, throwing an exception is less noise overall (and lets you say *why* the failure occurred). Try not to return `null` on failure

Comment: `null` can be a valid return-value of a method. So returning `null` in case of error is not good.

Comment: If or if not your method should throw an exception is essentially another question, which is already broadly described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions. Also have a look at this post: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/120355/is-it-better-to-return-null-or-empty-values-from-functions-methods-where-the-ret

Comment: It can be difficult to know if a method can return null or not, leading to either errors or code bloated with null checks. This have been mitigated with nullable reference types, but that is a fairly new paradigm. The try pattern is explicit, so there is less risk of it being used incorrectly.

Comment: Related: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/07/15/tester-doer-isomorphisms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TryParse` pattern is not (just) about preventing exceptions. It's a way to show the caller that the input could be invalid and that he/she can handle the `false`-case accordingly. So you get two information from the method:

1. the parsed/resolved value in case it succeeded
2. a `bool` that indicates if the value could be resolved successfully

Note that you can't get the second information from the value itself because whatever you return from the method in `false`-case it could be a valid value.

The only drawback of the `TryParse`-pattern, that is return a `bool` and the value as `out`-parameter, is, that you can't "chain" it with other method calls. That's why i sometimes provide a different way if i parse primitive types: return `Nullable<T>`:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static int? TryGetInt(this string input)
    {
        return int.TryParse(input, out int value) ? value : new int?();
    }
    // more methods like this...
}
```

> Why not just have the non-try method not throw exceptions?

Because often you can't do that because the exception comes not from your code. But as i've said, it's not about preventing exceptions but about helping the caller of the method to understand it and to handle the result.

> When would throwing an exception be better than just returning null?

In case of an exceptional case which is not normal program flow. But instead of returning `null` you should return a `bool`(try-get with `out`-parameter) or a nullable type(primitive types).

> If the decision comes down to having one type of method that just
> returns a nullable type (or some Result type), should this always be
> reflected in the method's name in the sense that it has to be prefixed
> with "Try"?

Yes, that would help to understand that the method also returns the information if it succeeded.

> Is providing both types of methods always better in every case?

No, that's just confusing people, what method should be used?!

> I am specifically working with manipulating a collection, and what I
> have is a bunch of methods like: void GetAt(position) bool
> TryGet(position, out item)

Sounds like a reasonable use-case for a `TryGet` but don't provide both. You haven't provided enough information though.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.
When would you provide one type of method and not the other?

Comment: I'm also think that the `TryXXX` is also because the old C# can not return 2 value.  and I think now  we can use `ValueTuple`   eg.   `(bool isSuccess, int value) TryParse(string val)` ,  and the new pattern  support  async method,  and the `out` version doesn't.
the reason of why do not use `Nullable<T>`   is because the `Nullable<T>` is come later than  those `Try***()`  method

Comment: @TheTall: use `Try`-pattern if it could fail because the parameter is invalid(for example invalid format), so if a `false` is likely because the input comes from the user. If it should not happen because it would be a bug, dont use `Try` but throw an exception and handle that somewhere else(proper logging ofc.).

Comment: @John: yes, the reason why `TryParse` was used everywhere was that nullable-types didn't exist before .NET 2.0

Comment: @TimSchmelter  @TheTall   do not use `try{   value = Int32.Parse("abc") } catch{ value=0   } `  if possible  , because the `Exception` is expensive  (it contained the stack and other information)        the cost  is expensive compare to  only create a `int` value.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That sounds like my use-case should never throw exceptions then. Sorry for not providing enough information. What can I provide that would be helpful in nailing down the right approach?

Comment: @John I've seen a lot of discussion about returning nullable types (or a `Result` type) being a better alternative to setting an `out` parameter. I get why that's the case and I think it'll be what I go with for my `Try` methods. Thanks

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sorry but I think I'm wrong about my use-case never throwing exceptions. If the given position is invalid then I think that's a good enough reason to throw an exception. But you mentioned that `Try` seems to be a good fit for what I'm trying to do. I'm not sure.

Comment: IMHO, if your TryFoo returns null when failing, it should probably be named FooOrDefault instead to better convey it.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the `Try`Pattern comes into play, when it happens quite regulary, that you don't have a match and not exceptional.

So depending on your specific scenario, how likely is it, that your class is being asked for something it can't provide? And even more, what can be done in such a case? Is there something easy the caller can do (e.g. calling some other `Try`-Method, fall back to something else) or is calling your method with an invalid parameter value really something exceptional and all you can do is throwing an exception to get out of the whole stack?

Depending on the answer to the above questions in each individual case I decide which route to go.